# Github API zip file naming structure change

Tags: git, github, repository

The github API is renaming the root folder name. Example of a public git: `https://api.github.com/repos/roots/sage/zipball/master` the downloaded file is renamed to: `roots-sage-9.0.9-83-ge7de7b2.zip` also the root folder name is renamed. This is realy bad for projects where the root folder name needs to be constant like WordPress plugins or templates.
Is there a way to select the downloaded file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub always generates an archive with a root directory including some revision information.  That may be a branch name, tag name, or the output of `git describe`, as you've seen in this case.

If you don't like that, you have some options:

- Clone the repository, possibly with `--depth 1`, and use `git archive` to generate your own zip or tar archive with your desired `--prefix` option (don't forget to include the trailing slash).
- Use the `-s` option of `bsdtar` to modify the archive name like so when extracting: `bsdtar -s '!^roots-sage-[^/]*!roots-sage!' -xvf archive.zip`.  GNU tar can't be used for zip files, but a similar option `--xform` will work for tar files.
- Repack the archive yourself manually, using `unzip`, `mv`, and `zip`, or for tar archives, `tar` and `mv`.

Note that if you are distributing something for Unix, tar archives are more frequently used than zip archives because they preserve permissions better.

As for the archive, the name is specified by the server but you don't have to honor it.  For example, you can use the `-o` option to `curl` to write the file with whatever name you'd like.  Using `curl` is customary on Unix systems, but if you'd like to use something else, see that tool's documentation for information.